# What is this swastika-looking symbol in John Hancock's family papers from circa 1762?

Tags: symbols, literary-english, handwriting, eighteenth-century-english

I was looking at the "From The Page" software and tried to transcribe a section of the Hancock family papers, and on Page 137 (seq. 139) the author used what seems to be swastikas to initialize some script. What could this be?
Second line in:

> Determined to be so 卐 will not willingly 卐 quietly subject myself

Citation: Hancock family papers, 1712-1854 (inclusive). Volume JH-6 John Hancock letterbook (business), 1762-1783. Mss:766 1712-1854 H234. Baker Library Historical Collections, Harvard Business School.

[image: Image of handwritten text]

Comment: maybe it's a symbol representing _and_? Like a stylized + sign.

Comment: [Google image search doesn't find anything](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiuUXrbqr4oJ8_1YjvLTX2gYJOOz8tUgL9mxZcouizi-kBAd9_1NyUDMkQQOsb5bRLWlRdu39hwlmBqekzB3D8ZuAl46M64E0QBd1fyvHb2s1Si_1EN1PV64w9sfzVPVmkV7NhnPQnjBRvSfi7mdK-FeBjcKG4FyVEOqYKXbZR-KCBuRGgXduHzqtUPGqjGLM42iVK6gJT0TzluqjhEdld6IF1RhmUhWnybvPmCsIbpG1seTVAk7YpajxFbiAQYWRY41SuiRJCO6N2wqBe8rzqUc1GxQu2VjN40GP7m1dFjYRXoj6JIswjvreYjFJHKv7U4sKHUKEr3BmR1ARDwr8fDgheaFbCxwA&hl=en)

Comment: Also there are more occurences of that glyph in the passage. In the previous line "I am free X determined to be so X will not willingly X quietly..." "We are a people worth answering X our trade so much to your advantage"

Comment: It doesn't look like a swastika to me but rather a stylized '+' like @Cascabel says. Also, I try some short words and sometimes they work and sometimes not. 'Or' works kind of, 'and' maybe.

Comment: This is **'&'**, not a swastika: *Determined to be so & will not willingly & quietly Subject myself* -- [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Wn08DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=%22Determined+to+be+so+*+will+not+willingly+*+quietly+subject+myself%22&source=bl&ots=npAbHRZh_Z&sig=ACfU3U1k7e_xBTE0E0iQEpnmMJoK62ne6Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0nZWNp9PuAhVCiFwKHdXPBk8Q6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Determined%20to%20be%20so%20*%20will%20not%20willingly%20*%20quietly%20subject%20myself%22&f=false) ///// Try googling *"Determined to be so * will not willingly * quietly subject myself"* (with "")

Comment: The first looks like a saguaro to me. The second is clearly an ampersand.

Comment: This is gonna sound like a strange question...but was the writer right-handed, or left-handed?

Comment: @Cascabel I think that _everywhere_ a saguaro is a North-American cactus. Carnegiea gigantea. Famed backdrop for Westerns. Perhaps the Nazis wouldn't have been as nasty if they'd adopted a cartoon saguaro as their trademark. Or Yosemite Sam as their leader.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because trivially available info on any reference

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Tried googling. The only result returned by Google is this question... Unless you hit the "Books" tab, I see. I guess the "All" tab isn't really all.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Put that as an answer, for that is what it is.

Comment: By saying swastika,  you are in effect being anachronistic...

Comment: The question asks for a deciphering of a written text.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*I am free & determined to be so & will not willingly & quietly subject myself to slavery.*

& = "and"

*I am free and determined to be so and will not willingly and quietly subject myself to slavery.*

Look carefully at the  circled symbols in the document. You can see that the first and last are clearly the standard ampersand symbol **&**.  The other two are sketchy versions where I guess the pen has for an instant lifted off the paper.

[image]

Now look at the following. I have added to the less clear ones without overwriting any part of them to show that they have the same form.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

Comment: So the gaps in the curvy parts are due to the quill pen running out of ink?

Comment: @Cascabel -  Possibly but is clear  that this writer uses this symbol a lot. It may just be a product of writing quickly or even carelessness.  I'l make a new picture to show the effect more clearly.

Comment: @Cascabel Many scribal abbreviations had glyph shapes in various hands which differ substantially from the fixed forms found in almost any typeface used with movable type. As befits an educated gentleman of his day, John Hancock's handwriting is really quite elegant here, and I see no reason to think his quill selectively ran out of ink for just these particular glyphs alone. He would surely have touched those up had it done so.

Comment: @tchrist Whoosh...You had me jumping around there. Just trying to eliminate obvious stuff. When I was studying Graphic Arts in the early 70s  we spent a year on writing with Crow Quill pens. I noticed back then that handedness, pressure, and type of ink had a heavy bearing on production.

Comment: @Cascabel: Or it could be just idiosyncratic handwriting.  Certainly the ampersand (which I use quite a lot) is one of the more difficult glyphs to do by hand, at least for me.  Hurray for keyboards!

Comment: @jamesqf Yes...idiosyncrasies of hand writing are much more apparent with a quill pen, while  ballpoints hide many of those. For example, the more pressure you put on the point of a quill, the wider the stroke. Up-sweeps and down-strokes produce different  size lines, depending on handedness.  Going against the point will sometimes create microscopic splatters. It is similar to calligraphy in this aspect.